# jQuery - .not() isn't working with .text()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dropdown that looks like this:

```
<select name="cc_dropdown[0]" id="cc-dropdown-0">
     <option value="">Select a card</option>
     <option value="0">***********1111</option>
     <option value="1" selected="selected">***********0005</option>
     <option value="-1">Use a new card</option>
</select>
```

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="select-cc-dropdown-0">
   <div class="selectBox" tabindex="0">
      <div class="sbContent">***********0005</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to get a collection of all the options in the dropdown whose text doesn't match the text in the `sbContent` div.

This is what I've tried:

```
var tmp = $('#select-cc-dropdown-0 .selectBox .sbContent').text();
$('#cc-dropdown-0 option').text().not(tmp);
```

`var tmp` does return the expected text (in this case, ***********0005). But when I try to string `.not()` after `.text()`, I get an error (TypeError: $(...).text(...).not is not a function).

How can I string these two bits together to get what I need?

Comment: Of course this doesn't work. `.text()` returns a string, not a jQuery object. This is a fairly basic jQuery question readily answered by the always-useful [jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/) Please do check there first before asking a question on [so].

Comment: .not() can not be used to manipulate strings. you should use some string comparision function instea.

Comment: @MattBall - it may be "of course" to you, but for those of us new to jquery, or who just don't spend much time with it, that's a distinction that gets missed, even after checking the API (which I did before posting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this doesn't work. [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) returns a string, not a jQuery object. Use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) (or [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not)) with [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

```
$('#cc-dropdown-0 option:not(:contains("' + tmp + '"))').text();
// or
$('#cc-dropdown-0 option').not(':contains("' + tmp + '")').text();
```

Comment: OK, technically this works. I guess my question wasn't worded carefully enough, or I'm really not looking at this the right way. Both of those options return a single string, with the text of all the available options concatenated, like this: "Select a card***********1111Use a new card". What I need is an actual collection of the options that don't match, so that I can remove an attribute from each one.

Comment: Just replace `.text()` with `.removeAttr('foo')` or `.removeProp('bar')`, depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Tomorrow. Brain about to explode after 18-hour workday.